# Adding Jobs to Quartz.net from string array

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am working on simpligying my code, but I have redundancy where it comes to starting my Quartz schedule. I was able to generalize many methods that needed to be run in sequence using this method(http://www.vcskicks.com/call-function.php) which let me put everything I wanted into a string array and loop over it, but not sure how to schedule the jobs.

The error I am getting is `NameSpace is a variable but used like a type` when initializing the `IJobDetail` under the AddJobsBool() method.

```
//Method Definitions    
public static bool RunJobsFromList(Array[,] JobTasks)
{
    bool ProcessingError = false;
    var MethodClass = "";
    var MethodName = "";
    int startDelay = 0;
    int Repeat = 0;
    foreach (string[] item in SyncTasks)
    {
        MethodClass = item[0];
        MethodName = item[1];
        startDelay = Convert.ToInt32(item[2]);
        Repeat = Convert.ToInt32(item[3]);
        AddJobs(MethodClass, MethodName, startDelay, Repeat);
    }

    Scheduling.CurrentSchedule.Start();

    return true;
}

public static bool AddJobs(string NameSpace, string methodName, string startDelay, string Repeat)
{
    var Space= Type.GetType(NameSpace);
    IJob FullMethod = Space.GetMethod(methodName) as IJob;      

    IJobDetail GenericJob = JobBuilder.CreateForAsync<NameSpace>().WithIdentity(methodName).Build();
    ITrigger GenericJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity(methodName)
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(Repeat).RepeatForever())
        .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(startDelay)).Build();
    Scheduling.CurrentSchedule.ScheduleJob(GenericJob, GenericJobTrigger);    

}

// How I am calling it
Array[,] JobList =new Array[,]
{                   //Method Class,       Method Name,  "startDelay", "Repeat"
    {new string[]{ "Program.Class1",       "Job1",       "0",    "5"}},
    {new string[]{ "Program.Class1",       "Job1",       "0",    "5"}}    
};
RunJobsFromList(JobList);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that you posted has multiple problems: `typeName` is an undefined variable but even if it was defined, it's being mis-used to get the name of a method.

You're trying to get a `Type` instance by calling `Type.GetType()` and then you're trying to cast that to `IJob`. That won't work - `Type` is not related to `IJob` - an instance of your job implementation would derive from `IJob` but the `Type` instance you get is not the instance of your job class - it's *an instance of the type of your job class*. Your `type` variable will always be null.

You're also calling

```
... = JobBuilder.CreateForAsync<NameSpace>(...)
```

but `NameSpace` is a string parameter to your function, not a type: it contains (part of) the name of a type but it's a string, not the type itself. You can only put a type name inside the `<...>` when instantiating a generic type.

You'll need to use `Type.GetType()` to get the type of your job class and then probably call `JobBuilder.Create()` - that one takes a `Type` parameter. You won't be able to use the async call as above because there the type needs to be known at compile time (which you don't since you build your type name from strings at run-time).

Comment: Thank you xxbbcc, you are right that I had some careless mistakes as I was trying to sanitize the code for posting. I am trying to JobBuilder.Create() as you suggested and got it working, but interestingly you can't have more than one job of the same name - even if they are listed in separate groups. In fact when looking at it using `GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs()` everything was in the `DEFAULT` group even though I specified a different group name.